# Keydown repeatedly triggers. Can that be avoided?

Tags: javascript, event-listener, keydown

How can I edit this code so the function functForward is only triggered once upon pressing and holding down the key?

The problem is that when holding down the key the function will be triggered repeatedly and a kind of staggering happens. That then will lead to a continuation of functForward long after i released the key.

Any input welcome.

```js
    var addEvent = document.addEventListener ? function(target, type, action) {
      if (target) {
        target.addEventListener(type, action, false);
      }
    } : function(target, type, action) {
      if (target) {
        target.attachEvent('on' + type, action, false);
      }
    }

    addEvent(document, 'keydown', function(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
      if (key === 87) {
        functForward();
      }
    });
    addEvent(document, 'keyup', function(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
      if (key === 87) {
        functStopDrive();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"How can I edit this code so the function functForward is only triggered once upon pressing and holding down the key?"*

All modern browsers support `addEventListener()` so the `attachEvent()` isn't needed unless you intend to make your own customized event. In short: do not just edit the code you have, use something more streamlined and easier to understand.

The functions funcForward and funcStopDrive are not defined in the code provided, it's impossible to edit code around an unknown function let alone trying to edit code in order to get unknown functions working.

Once again holding down a key so mystery function X does something when a key is held down. How does one quantify that into a parameter of distance and time or state without having any clue what X function does and how its done?

In the following Demo:

- There are 3 events and 3 event handlers. They each have a class that has animated styles.
- Make sure the test area is focused (click anywhere in the area to do so).
- simply tap the <kbd>spacebar</kbd>.
- Try tapping the spacebar once then when the jet is halfway tap the spacebar again, it looks cool.

### Demo

```js
var jet = document.querySelector('.fa-fighter-jet');

document.addEventListener('keydown', climb)
document.addEventListener('keypress', cruise);
document.addEventListener('keyup', dive);

jet.focus();

function climb(e) {
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  if (key === 32) {
    jet.classList.toggle('up');
  }
}

function cruise(e) {
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  if (key === 32) {
    jet.classList.toggle('go');
  }
}

function dive(e) {
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  if (key === 32) {
    jet.classList.toggle('down');
  }
}
```

```css
.fa {
  display: block;
  
}

.up {
  transform: translate(500px, -200px);
  transition: .75s ease-in;
}

.go {
  transform: translateX(500px);
  transition: .75s ease-out;
}

.down {
  transform: translate(500px, 200px);
  transition: .75s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />


<i class='fa fa-fighter-jet fa-2x'></i>
```